# Pass ID via Html.BeginForm and Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: c#, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm currently trying to find out what´s the MVC-way to solve the following problem:

I have a table (index view) based on a model and my first row has a button to change one cell of this row. When the button is pressed a popup is shown (via `Ajax.ActionLink`), which asks for an additional comment. The popup view is realised with a Partial View and a `Html.BeginForm`. After adding a comment and clicking the submit button the updated index view is shown.

At the moment I calculate the id of the first-row item before the updated index view is shown, because I don't know how to pass this id via the `Ajax.ActionLink` at first **and** the `Html.BeginForm` afterwards.

The whole process looks like this:

**Ajax.ActionLink in Index View:**

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Update", "Update", null,
                            new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "result", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "openPopup()" },
                            new { @class = "btn btn-info"})
```

**Update Partial View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <p>Comment here:</p>
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" id="comment" required></textarea>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-info" />
}
```

**ActionResults in Controller**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public PartialViewResult Update()
        {                   
            return PartialView();
        }
    
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string comment)
        {
            
            //Here I calculate the ID, which represents the first row
            //I would like to have this ID as a paramter, additional to comment

            int maxID = dbContext.db.Max(m => m.pmc_id);
            db x= dbContext.db.Where(m => m.pmc_id == maxID).FirstOrDefault();

            //...Update database etc.

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what is the question exactly?

Comment: if your question is how to pass ID you can pass via link itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first pass the Id to view with for example viewbag or some view model in here I chose ViewBag

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string comment)
        {
            
            //Here I calculate the ID, which represents the first row
            //I would like to have this ID as a paramter, additional to comment

            int maxID = dbContext.db.Max(m => m.pmc_id);
            db x= dbContext.db.Where(m => m.pmc_id == maxID).FirstOrDefault();

            //...Update database etc.
            ViewBag.CurrentId = calculatedId;//saved Id to pass to View
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

lets add into the view the Id

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Index"))
    {
        <input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.CurrentId" name="Id"/>
        <div class="form-group">
            <h4>Title</h4>
            <p>Comment here:</p>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" id="comment" required></textarea>
        </div>
    
        <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-info" />
    }
```

now lets get the Id parameter with mvc parser

```
  [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult Update(int Id)//here is your id
    {                   
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Comment: please mark as answer or more clarify your question